# Javascript won't validate my dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, html-select

I'm having small trouble with javascript validation. I need to validate the select dropdown in my form. I can validate all fields so far but somehow I cannot validate the select dropdown list? Can someone help me validate my form?

Here is my javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

if( document.form1.Email.value != "" )
   {
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail(document.form1.Email);
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }
   }
} 

function validate()
{
//username password First_n Last_n Company Mobile Email Residence



   if( document.form1.First_n.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please enter your first name!" );
     document.form1.First_n.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Last_n.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please enter your last name!" );
     document.form1.Last_n.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.username.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please enter your username!" );
     document.form1.username.focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   if( document.form1.password.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please enter your password!" );
     document.form1.password.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Mobile.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide us your mobile number!" );
     document.form1.Mobile.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Email.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide us your Email!" );
     document.form1.Email.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
var yourSelect = document.getElementById('Residence');
   alert(yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value)
   if(yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value == '' )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your country!" );
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Email.value != "" )
   {
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail(document.form1.Email);
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }
   }

   return( true );
}
</script>
```

And my form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_new.php" onsubmit="return(validate(false));">
<div style="clear:both;padding:0px 10px 0 10px;margin-bottom:40px;">
<h5>Interested in</h5>
<input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="Hosting" type="radio" checked>
<label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Hosting</label>
<input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="Email accounts" type="radio"
><label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Email accounts</label>
</div> 
<div style="clear-both;">
<input name="First_n" type="text" placeholder="First Name*" class="login-text-lbl-pink-no-width" id="First_n">     
<input name="Last_n" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" class="login-text-lbl-pink-no-width" id="Last_n">              
</div>
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username*" class="login-text-lbl-pink-no-width" id="username"><br/>
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password*" class="login-text-lbl-pink-no-width" id="password"><br/>
<input name="Company" type="text" placeholder="Company" class="login-text-lbl-pink-odd" id="Company">              <br/>
<input name="Mobile" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number*" class="pink-transparent-item" id="Mobile">              <br/>
<input name="Email" type="text"  placeholder="Email*" class="login-text-lbl-pink-odd" id="Email">              <br/>
<select name="Residence" id="Residence" style="background-color: rgba(240, 96, 96, 0.62);border: none;-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;appearance: none;height: 40px;font-style: italic;width: 270px;padding: 10px;margin: 5px;color: #552726;border-radius: 5px;border: none;float: left;" class="required">
<option value="zero" selected>Country*</option>
<option value="US">America</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
<option value="IT">Italy</option>
<option value="HK">Hong Kong</option><br/>
<input name="domain" class="login-text-lbl-pink-odd" type="text" style="width:350px;margin-bottom:40px;" placeholder="Existing domain" id="domain">              <br/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style='font-family: "Neo Sans Light", Verdana, Tahoma;' class="login-button-pink">
</form>
```

Comment: What does "won't validate" mean? Does it not display the alert when it should? Does it display the alert when it shouldn't? Does the form submit continue when it shouldn't? Or...? And, finally, are there any errors shown in your browser's Javascript console?

Comment: @nnnnnn it wont give me an alert and return false so the form doesn't post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the email validation that happens just before the country validation, because if an email address is entered it returns from the function regardless of whether the email passed validation, so it never gets to the country bit:

```
   if( document.form1.Email.value != "" )
   {
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail(document.form1.Email);
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }else      
          return true;       // delete this line, and the else
   }
```

You want to return false if there's a problem, but you don't want to return true until the end of the function.

**UPDATE:** The code now shown in the updated question doesn't work because:

- You deleted the `validateEmail()` function declaration (replacing it with a copy of the code I said to change at the end of `validate()` - unless that was just a weird copy/paste error in the question)
- You changed the `if` test on the country to check for an empty string, but didn't update the corresponding `value="zero"` to be `value=""`

If you fix those it works as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/58A7K/

Note also that the code I showed above can be simplified - you don't need the `ret` variable:

```
if( document.form1.Email.value != "" ) {
    if (!validateEmail(document.form1.Email)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: changed the code but same problem... I've updated the code if you can please help me

Comment: You changed the code, but you did more changes than I said to do and those other changes broke it. See my update and [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58A7K/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with following code:

```
if( document.form1.Email.value != "" )
   {
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail(document.form1.Email);
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }else 
          return true;
   }
```

In the above code, when user enters a valid email, your are returning TRUE as a result the code for validating country is never executed.

Remove the else part from above code snippet.

Comment: changed the code but same problem... I've updated the code if you can please help me

Comment: change yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value == '' to yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value == 'zero' because you have set <option value="zero" selected>Country*</option>

Comment: or remove zero from <option value="zero" selected>Country*</option> and make it <option value="" selected>Country*</option>